# Extracting from a 2D df and adding value to 1D df in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to extract information from a 2d data frame where I have rows A through H and columns 1-12. Each cell has a different number. My second dataframe only has one column with the combined information, for example A1, A2, etc. I want to set a for loop so that I can do df1.iloc and select the coordinates. But I don't want to type 96 rows, so I am thinking a for loop would be helpful but I don't know how to do it.
I am fairly new so I don't know much of the tricks.

df1 would be:

|  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 237 | 543 | 300 | 256 | 343 | 122 |
| B | 435 | 313 | 150 | 635 | 847 | 321 |

df2 would be:

```
well=['A1','A2','A3','B1','B2','B3']
```

I would like to make a df3 that looks like:

| Well | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | 237 |
| A2 | 543 |
| A3 | 300 |
| B1 | 435 |
| B2 | 313 |
| B3 | 150 |

So far what I have is:

```
    df3=pd.DataFrame()
    for i in df2:
        if i.contains('A'):
           row=df1.iloc[1]
           if i.contains('1'):
              value=row.iloc[1]
        df3.append(i,value)
```

I know that col # will always be the same for iloc.
So can I assign A-H as 1-8 and then somehow select the number after the letter in df2 as the iloc value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) `df1` and [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) from `well`:

```
df3 = df1.stack()
df3.index = df3.index.map(lambda s: ''.join(map(str, s)))
df3 = df3.reindex(df2['well']).reset_index(name='Value')
```

`df3`:

```
  Well  Value
0   A1    237
1   A2    543
2   A3    300
3   B1    435
4   B2    313
5   B3    150
```

DataFrames used:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    1: {'A': 237, 'B': 435}, 2: {'A': 543, 'B': 313},
    3: {'A': 300, 'B': 150}, 4: {'A': 256, 'B': 635},
    5: {'A': 343, 'B': 847}, 6: {'A': 122, 'B': 321}
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'well': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3']})
```

---

Explanations:

1. Stack produces a series:

```
df3 = df1.stack()
```

`df3`:

```
A  1    237
   2    543
   3    300
   4    256
   5    343
   6    122
B  1    435
   2    313
   3    150
   4    635
   5    847
   6    321
dtype: int64
```

---

2. Collapse the MultiIndex into a single index with [`Index.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html):

```
df3.index = df3.index.map(lambda s: ''.join(map(str, s)))
```

`df3`:

```
A1    237
A2    543
A3    300
A4    256
A5    343
A6    122
B1    435
B2    313
B3    150
B4    635
B5    847
B6    321
dtype: int64
```

---

3. Grab `well` from `df2` and [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
df3 = df3.reindex(df2['well'])
```

```
Well
A1    237
A2    543
A3    300
B1    435
B2    313
B3    150
dtype: int64
```

*If well is a `list` as it appears in the OP turn it into a `Series` with the name `well` and `reindex` from that instead:

```
well = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3']
df3 = df3.reindex(pd.Series(well, name='well'))
```

Or `reindex` directly from the `list` but then the axis will need renamed before resetting the index:

```
well = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3']
df3 = df3.reindex(well).rename_axis(index='Well')
```

---

4. [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) to convert to a DataFrame (and give the `Value` column a name):

```
df3 = df3.reindex(df2['well']).reset_index(name='Value')
```

`df3`:

```
  Well  Value
0   A1    237
1   A2    543
2   A3    300
3   B1    435
4   B2    313
5   B3    150
```

Comment: What if 'df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    1: {'A': 237, 'B': 435, 'C':900}, 2: {'A': 543, 'B': 313, 'C':1200},
    3: {'A': 300, 'B': 150, 'C':1600}, 4: {'A': 256, 'B': 635, 'C':900},
    5: {'A': 343, 'B': 847, 'C':1200}, 6: {'A': 122, 'B': 321, 'C':1600}
})'  and I want the dataframe: 'df3=pd.DataFrame({
    'name':{'A1':237,'A2':543,'A3':300,'A4':256,'A5':343,'A6':122,
            'B1':435,'B2':313,'B3':150,'B4':635,'B5':847,'B6':321},
    'Time':{'A1':900,'A2':1200,'A3':1600,'A4':900,'A5':1200,'A6':1600,
            'B1':900,'B2':1200,'B3':1600,'B4':900,'B5':1200,'B6':1600}
})'

Comment: That actually seems like a different question because of how additional columns are saved based on the C index. I don't have enough room in the comments to fully go through my thoughts, and it doesn't make sense to alter this question which has been asked and answered. I'd be happy to look at your new question which outlines specifically how this transformation is to occur as well as any other relevant factors that would be hard to include in the comments.